# What is the diameter of my lens?

Tags: lens, canon, dslr

So recently I bought a used lens - Canon ef 28-80mm f/3.5-5.6 usm with the metal mount but it came with no lens cap and I want to buy one now but I can't see the diameter of the lens on it anywhere which I need to buy a lens cap, do any of you guys have this lens or happen to know the diameter of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search on the internet suggests it is 58mm. It is often referred to as the 'filter diameter'. Also, as a general rule, on the lens somewhere, maybe around the front optic, there is usually a little 'o' with a line through it like this `ø` followed by a number of mm. That should be the size to look for. Also, if you have a camera shop nearby you can take the lens in with you, they will probably have various sizes in stock, and will find one to fit it.